# Multiple jQuery document.read event handlers running in wrong order

Tags: javascript, telerik, jquery, telerik-mvc

I recently added a feature to our ASP.NET MVC web application.  There's a page that is displayed when the user clicks on an item in a table.  The page uses AJAX to display a partial view in a single `div` in the page's HTML.  The partial view uses the Telerik Kendo UI to define and display dialogs and `DropDownList` controls.  This is complicated in that the JavaScript imports are all on the `View` for the page, while the `PartialView` just builds the HTML to be displayed in the `div`.

The JavaScript I wrote on the page includes a `jQuery document.ready` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        if ( $('#details-map').val() != '' )
            $('#details-map').remove();

        var urlTail = '?t=' + (new Date().getTime());

        // Make the AJAX call and load the result into the details box.
        $('#detailsbox').load('<%= Url.Action("Details") %>' + '/' + '<%: Model.Id %>' + urlTail, displayDetails);
    }
)
```

This works fine when I run the application on my localhost.  The problem appears when I deploy the page to our development server.  In this case, there's an additional `document.ready` event handler that's emitted to very end of the page by the Telerik Kendo / ASP.net MVC extensions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if(!jQuery.telerik) jQuery.telerik = {};
jQuery.telerik.cultureInfo=...;
});
//]]>
</script>
```

On this page, the `$(document).ready` event handler I wrote runs before the Telerik handler, and my code clearly depends on the Telerik handler running first.  When mine runs first, I get a JavaScript error that says "jQuery.telerik.load is not a function'.

Since this does not happen on my localhost, how do I make sure that the second document ready event handler is run first?

Edit:

After more research, I've found that the problem is that the two scripts mentioned in my answer, which are supposed to be written to the page via the following line in the Master Page used by my page:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true).jQuery(false).DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(false).Compress(false)) %>
```

Are not being loaded.  In other words, the above line does nothing.  It works on another page that uses the same Master Page, though.  I've placed a breakpoint on the line and it is executing.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're either going to have to make it show up after the second one on the page OR do something I hate to suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function init {
        /* all your code that needs to be run after telerik is loaded */
    }
    if ( $.telerik ) {
        init();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function check4telerik() {
            if ( $.telerik ) {
                return init();
            }
            setTimeout(check4telerik, 0);
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

So, if `$.telerik` is loaded, it runs, otherwise it polls until it's set, and when it is set, it runs the code. It's not pretty, but if you don't have more control, it's probably your only option, unless `$.telerik` emits some kind of event that you can hook into.

Comment: The weird thing is I can't find the second `document.ready` event handler in the code emitted by my localhost on the page anywhere.  Which begs the question how does the telerik function get initialized in that case?  I think I'm going to have to go with the polling function.  I don't like it much either, but I don't see how to get my code to appear after the telerik code.  I'll check to see if there's an event in the telerik code I can hook into.

Comment: Evidently, what I thought was the problem is not the problem.  I found a way to get my document ready code to appear in the same block as the code added by Telerik after their code, and the problem still happens.  I even tried adding your code and $.telerik is defined so the timer never runs.  My code runs to completion, but other code that is executed once the partial is loaded craps out with the "jQuery.telerik.load is not a function" error (in Firefox; similar but different messages occur in IE & Chrome).

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. I'm not at all familiar with Telerik or Kendo, so I may have reached my knowledge limit on this question. You could check for the existence of `$.telerik && $.telerik.load`?

Comment: I've fixed the problem.  I am going to post another answer explaining what worked.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few hours working on this, I finally got it to work.  The problem turned out to be that two JavaScript files that are used by the Telerik `DropdownList` control and `Window` control were not being loaded.

In spelunking through the JavaScript on the page, I came across this script that was generated by Telerik:

```
if(!jQuery.telerik){
jQuery.ajax({
url:"/Scripts/2011.3.1306/telerik.common.min.js",
dataType:"script",
cache:false,
success:function(){
jQuery.telerik.load(["/Scripts/2011.3.1306/jquery-1.6.4.min.js","/Scripts/2011.3.1306/telerik.common.min.js","/Scripts/2011.3.1306/telerik.list.min.js"],function(){ ... });
}});}else{
jQuery.telerik.load(["/Scripts/2011.3.1306/jquery-1.6.4.min.js","/Scripts/2011.3.1306/telerik.common.min.js","/Scripts/2011.3.1306/telerik.list.min.js"],function(){ ... });
}
```

This script was emitted by a call to `Html.Telerik.DropdownListFor()` in my partial view.  I'm guessing that the code to include for the two JavaScript files mentioned in the code, telerik.common.min.js and telerik.list.min.js, was not emitted since the call was on a partial view.  Or I was supposed to include them all along & didn't know it (I'm very new to these controls).  Oddly, everything worked when I ran it locally, so I don't get it.

In any case, I added two `<script>` tags to my `View` to include these files and everything started working.  That is, I added the following tags to my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/2011.3.1306/telerik.common.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/2011.3.1306/telerik.list.min.js"></script>
```

Live and learn.